# ef core: mapping value object using OwnsMany requires primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a class

```
public class Document
{
    public string TranId { get; set; }        
    public Record Record { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string TranId { get; set; }    
    public List<DataResult> DataResults { get; set; }
}

public class DataResult
{
    public string DataSourceName { get; set; }
    public List<DataField> DataFields { get; set; }
    public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }        
}
```

I want to map Record and DataResult classes as Value objects so I tried to map as

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Document> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Document");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.TranId);

    builder.OwnsOne(a => a.Record, a =>
    {
        a.ToTable("Doc_Record");
        a.Property(p => p.TranId).HasMaxLength(100)
            .HasColumnName("TranID")
            .HasDefaultValue("");                          
            a.OwnsMany(x => x.DataResults, x =>
                {
                    x.ToTable("Doc_Rec_DataResults");
                    x.Property(p => p.DataSourceName).HasMaxLength(150)
                        .HasColumnName("DataSourceName")
                        .HasDefaultValue("");                                   
                });
    }
}
```

When I try to add this migration it errors with a message:

> The entity type 'DataResult' requires a primary key to be defined.

- And why it requires primary key cause I'm trying to map as a value
  object?

Someone suggested using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types) and I try to add

```
a.OwnsMany(x => x.DataResults, x =>
{
    x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("RecordId");
    x.ToTable("Doc_Rec_DataResults");
    x.Property(p => p.DataSourceName).HasMaxLength(150)
    .HasColumnName("DataSourceName")
    .HasDefaultValue("");                                   
});
```

but this approach is not working cause `WithOwner` is available from `.net core 3` where I'm using `.net core 2` (and do I really need to add `RecordId` property into `Record` class (it's a value object).

**It would be great if someone can provide an example of how to map collection of value objects with `OwnsMany` in `EF Core 2`.**

Comment: For collections of owned types a key (shadow property) is required: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks, is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: The link contains an example.

Answer (score 3):

In this ef core 2.2 [example](https://www.nankov.com/posts/improved-support-value-objects-ef-core-22), we have a `Company` that owns a collection of `Addresses`, here's the implementation. note that i omitted some useful code to stick to the point, refer to the full example for further explanation. Also note that this feature `OwnsMany()` is not available in pre ef core 2.2

```
public class CompanyAddress
{   
    public string City { get; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; }
}


public class Company
{
    private List<CompanyAddress> addresses = new List<CompanyAddress>();

    public Guid Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IEnumerable<CompanyAddress> Addresses { get => this.addresses; }

    public void AssignAddress(CompanyAddress address)
    {
        var exists = this.addresses.Contains(address);

        if (!exists)
        {
            this.addresses.Add(address);
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().OwnsMany<CompanyAddress>("Addresses", a =>
    {
        a.HasForeignKey("CompanyId");
        a.Property(ca => ca.City);
        a.Property(ca => ca.AddressLine1);
        a.HasKey("CompanyId", "City", "AddressLine1");
    });
}
```

[here's a repo](https://github.com/milannankov/EfCoreValueObjects) of full solution for the article's owner